# How to not expose a 3rd party library on the global scope?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am writing a bookmarklet that uses another 3rd party library in order to perform some of its functions. How could I make use of the 3rd party library in the bookmarklet without exposing the library on the global scope?

Source Code is currently being committed in - https://github.com/shanti2530/bookmarklets
The library in question is moment.js which currently is being exposed on the global scope if the user uses the bookmarklet.

Comment: How is `moment.js` being included in your bookmarklet and can you modify it?

Comment: Currently, I am including moment.js by using the grunt task to concatenate the files with the actual bookmarklet file. I am also considering using the https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-includes which would allow me to include the moment.js file inside the bookmarklet file

Comment: considering this is a bookmarklet, what is impact of using moment in global scope? Could always check for it's existence in page before adding it if that is a concern

Comment: I could check if it already exists before pulling it, but my concern is that I will be injecting 3rd party libraries on the global scope of webpages I do not know of - which means I am potentially affecting them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're just including the moment.js code in your own bookmarklet, you can just put the moment.js code inside your outer function.  That will make it available to you to use.

To make no global variables, you will have to edit the moment.js source because it explicitly creates global symbols regardless of how it is included.   I haven't studied its source extensively, but it looks like the function `makeGlobal()` is where it defines its interface.  You could modify that to add the moment function as a method on an object you declare in your function `f()` so you don't affect the global scope.

It looks like you would modify this line:

```
// makes moment function globally available
this['moment'] = moment;
```

to change how the `moment()` function is accessible.

Comment: @shanti - I'm not sure what you're asking.  You use an editor to paste the moment.js code into your `function f()`.  Also, see my additional comments on keeping moment.js from making global symbols.

Comment: Ok I will take a look at the makeGlobal function defined for momentjs